# sed: "repetition-operator operand invalid" using capturing groups

Tags: sed

**Standard regex**

I have a (partial) JSON string like so:

```
"99887":{"foo":"99887","bar":"paul"},"88776":{"foo":"88776"...
```

I need to get rid off the number string before each `{` to produce this:

```
{"foo":"99887","bar":"paul"},{"foo":"88776"...
```

For plain regex I'd use the pattern `("\d{5}"\:)(\{)` and keep `$2`.

**sed**

I'm having difficulties turning this into a sed command:

```
sed 's/\("\d{5}":\)\(\{\)/\2/g'
```

produces the error message

> error: repetition-operator operand invalid

In other contexts this messages seems to relate to the fact that `sed` does not support look-ahead/behind (which I don't use).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the problems of your sed are:

- you didn't use `-r`, so sed won't use extended regex
- `\d`, `{5}` won't be recognized by sed, `\{` is not valid either because it is not closed

(without `-r`, you could use `\{5\}`; with `-r`, you could `{5}`)

this line should give you the expected output:

```
 sed 's/"[0-9]*":{/{/g' file
```

Comment: Arrghh, yes, even my initial regex pattern isn't very straight forward. Good to know `sed` doesn't support `\d` and `{n}`.

Comment: if you add `-r` option, `{n}` would be supported.

Comment: @MarcelStör I believe it's `-E` on Mac OS X instead of `-r`.

Comment: @DavidW. thx for the info. I don't have much experience with bsd sed. but there should be something similar with -r.